# AuthorityKeyIdentifier missing from keypair generated with java keytool

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls

Background: I'm trying to set up a QA/test environment for a system comprising (1) a web application configured for HTTPS connections, and (2) a Python-based client application running on a mobile device. The installer for the web application requests a JKS file, which is to contain the keypair the server will supply to its clients for validation and encryption.

Disclaimer: I'm a rank amateur when it comes to SSL certificates and related subjects, working in learn-as-I-go mode. Please keep any answers dumbed down to a layman's level.

The problem:

I've been wrestling with java keytool, trying to make it generate a usable JKS entry for the web application's purposes. The problem is that any entry I generate, lacks an AuthorityKeyIdentifier element. It has a SubjectKeyIdentifier (of course) and using  [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) I've found how to add SubjectAlternativeName and other elements... but nothing I can find tells me how to get the AuthorityKeyIdentifier.

I suspect the normal means for this involves generating a CSR and getting it signed by a CA, but since this is strictly an internal QA environment, I'd much prefer to stick with self-signed. As I understand it, a self-signed JKS entry can -- and should -- have an AuthorityKeyIdentifier whose KeyIdentifier is a duplicate of the one in the SubjectKeyIdentifier. But like I said, I'm stuck on how to obtain that using java keytool.

Can anyone advise or instruct on how to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `keytool`'s list of possible extensions is limited and does not include the Authority Key Identifier you need.

Therefore, instead, use `openssl` to create the self-signed certificate; convert the certificate and private key into a PKCS#12 file; finally, if required, convert this to a JKS.

First, create a configuration file for `openssl` and save it as `openssl.conf` in your current directory:

```
[ req ]

# The size of the keys in bits:
default_bits       = 2048

# The message digest for self-signing the certificate
# sha1 or sha256 for best compatability, although most
# OpenSSL digest algorithm can be used.
# md4,md5,mdc2,rmd160,sha1,sha256
default_md = sha256

# Don't prompt for the DN, use configured values instead
# This saves having to type in your DN each time.

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default
distinguished_name = req_dn

# Extensions added while singing with the `openssl req -x509` command
x509_extensions = x509_ext

[ req_dn ]

countryName            = GB
stateOrProvinceName    = Somewhere
organizationName       = Example
commonName             = Example Web Service

[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always

subjectAltName = @alt_names

# No basicConstraints extension is equal to CA:False
# basicConstraints      = critical, CA:False

keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = example.org
DNS.2 = www.example.org
```

Next, create a self-signed certificate and private key:

Note: the `-nodes` option allows you to create an **unprotected** private key without a passphrase, as the PKCS#12 will have one instead.  If you need the private key to have a passphrase, simply remove this option.

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -days 720 -keyout selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.pem -config openssl.conf
```

Convert these two into a single PKCS#12:

Note: the `-name` option should be the keystore alias.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out selfsigned.p12 -in selfsigned.pem -inkey selfsigned.key -name MyApp
```

Java can use a PKCS#12 as a keystore, but if you insists on JKS, convert with:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore selfsigned.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore selfsigned.jks -deststoretype jks
```

`keytool` will warn you that JKS is a proprietary format and suggest PKCS#12, then ask for the **new** JKS passphrase first (twice), before prompting for the PKCS#12 passphrase.

You can confirm the certificate has everything you want by exporting:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore selfsigned.jks -alias SelfSigned -file selfsigned.crt
```

Finally, check it:

```
keytool -printcert -file selfsigned.crt
```

which should show something similar to:

```
Owner: CN=Example Web Service, O=Example, ST=Somewhere, C=GB
Issuer: CN=Example Web Service, O=Example, ST=Somewhere, C=GB
Serial number: 1fc84b98026e8b0b6d276ecbfc309dd7201bbb08
Valid from: Fri May 01 20:13:04 BST 2020 until: Thu Apr 21 20:13:04 BST 2022
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: B4:F0:A3:26:C8:7A:75:B1:32:55:0A:EC:31:4F:93:20:53:35:3E:A6
     SHA256: F4:97:EA:08:52:03:4B:F4:FB:9F:64:88:69:E6:81:1E:28:95:F8:E3:39:FE:24:C0:48:40:70:33:70:4E:94:0B
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F7 7F AA 69 52 DF 41 25   F2 F2 AC E7 5E D8 A7 43  ...iR.A%....^..C
0010: EF C9 92 50                                        ...P
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: www.example.com
  DNSName: www.example.org
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F7 7F AA 69 52 DF 41 25   F2 F2 AC E7 5E D8 A7 43  ...iR.A%....^..C
0010: EF C9 92 50                                        ...P
]
]
```

Finally, once you're happy with the results, make sure you **securely** delete the unprotected private key if you have one.

Comment: The detailed steps are very much appreciated.  Thanks!